# Kudu sync does not copy satellite assemblies to web job directory

Tags: git, azure, kudu

I'm using Kudu to deploy to an Azure Webapp from Git. Today I discovered that the satellite assemblies that contain translations (generated from standard resx files) are not copied to the WebJob destination directory. E.g. the `de\MyLib.resources.dll` file is present in the web app's `bin` directory, but not in the web job directory, even though the web job executable references `MyLib`.

As a consequence, my web job does not have the necessary resources available, which is a problem because I'm trying to send localized emails from the job.

**Is this a bug, or am I missing a configuration option to instruct Kudu to deploy the satellite assemblies as well?**

Edit: I also created an [issue on the kudu sync github site](https://github.com/projectkudu/KuduSync/issues/27).

Comment: Lets continue this discussion on github, I don't think stackoverflow is the right platform for this kind of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has also been reported as [Github issue by someone else](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1503). Apparently the problem lies in an MSBuild script in the `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` package. Unfortunately, the fix described by *@bradygaster* has still not been released.

### Temporary Solution

I created a patched version of `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` 1.3.0 that differs from that package by just the [fix described by bradygaster](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1503#issuecomment-94075022).

The patched nuget package has the ID [Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.SatelliteAssemblyFix](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.SatelliteAssemblyFix/1.0.3).

I hope that Microsoft fixes the original package and releases an update soon.

### Workaround

**This workaround does only work if the satellite assemblies are built as part of the web application.**

Use an XCOPY command to copy the satellite assemblies after Kudu Sync has completed:

```
xcopy   
   "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\bin\*" 
   "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\app_data\jobs\continuous\mywebjob\" 
   /Y /E
```

(line breaks added for readability).

Comment: This has been fixed in the 1.0.6 release of Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish/1.0.6